# Bootstrap 5 не работает модальное окно

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap5

не работает модальное окно не могу понять в чем причина, ошибок в консоли нет, делал все по официальной документации.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="Форма администратора">
<title>Учет техники | Администратор</title>

<!-- Bootstrap стили CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Иконки стили CSS -->
<link  href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" 
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
                 dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените
`data-toggle="modal"` --> `data-bs-toggle="modal"`

`data-target="#exampleModal"` --> `data-bs-target="#exampleModal"`

`data-dismiss="modal"` --> `data-bs-dismiss="modal"`

Пример

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало, а почему интересно на офф сайте это не указано?

Comment: Я копировал код с сайта переведенного на русскую версию, там было подругому, видимо лучше пользоваться оригиналом

Comment: @Bastard_Ape все указано https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/